# How can I prompt a user for an input and display something within the same line as well?

Tags: c++, formatting

Basically what I have currently is this:

```
//generates the menu
void menu(int TL, string title) {
    char a;

    //menu layout
    cout << title << endl;
    emptyLine(TL);
    centreHeading(TL, "OPTIONS");
    emptyLine(TL);
    centreText(TL, "(1) PLAY");
    centreText(TL, "(2) SET GAME LENGTH");
    centreText(TL, "(3) SET ROW LENGTH");
    centreText(TL, "(4) PEG SETTINGS");
    centreText(TL, "(9) HELP");
    centreText(TL, "(0) EXIT GAME");
    emptyLine(TL);
    cout << "|" << setw(19) << ""; cin >> a; cout << setw(19) << "|" << endl;
}
```

And I see this:

[Here I use 6 as the input. Notice that the cin >> automatically moves to a new line after the input, and so the | is out of place.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvOcQ.png)

How can we make sure that we see this instead?:

[Notice that the input 6 is still there, but the | is on the same line as the input, circled in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUiRN.png)

I have tried searching for a solution but it seems that others are more interested in how to prevent the \n character from being read by a subsequent getline() or some sort.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is probably easier to use a library for this like `ncurses`.

Comment: You can't, as far as I know. In most systems, the input will only get sent to your program after you press enter, which also moves the cursor to the next line.